# Getting modals to work in Meteor.js when page rerenders

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've managed to get bootstrap 3 modals working in my meteor project, but when the page rerenders, the screen just goes grey and freezes and the only way to unfreeze it is to refresh the page.

Why does this happen and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Would need more details on the scenario. I am working with meteor & bootstrap3 as well and all is OK up until now.

Comment: I was also finding them okay, but when they started becoming more dynamic and other things were changing in the background I started to run into problems. I think just implementing modals myself is the best solution. Not a lot of code. See my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is more of a comment then an answer, but I don't have the rep to comment.

I would have to see more code to determine the issue, but have you tried to do a data-dismiss on the modal during the Template.YourTemplate.rendered. Just to see if that is truly what is causing the issue. At least from there, you can work backwards.

Comment: If by data-dismiss you mean $('#myModal').modal('hide'); then yes. I tried like 10 different things, but could never get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this Bootstrap 2 example useful:

https://github.com/alanning/meteor-modal-example

Live demo:

http://modal-example.meteor.com/

Answer (score 0):

This cookbook is a great resource and what I'm going to do to solve my problem:
https://github.com/awatson1978/meteor-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/pages.dialogs.md

It's just implementing modals myself...

(I got this answer from meteor-talk Google group from Abigail Watson).